# Assign VBA array to new variable

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

I am trying to assign a two-dimensional Variant array to a variable, which for some reason doesn't work.

```
Function getClusters() As Variant()

Dim numberOfClusters, numberOfDifferentPartsPlusCaption, i, k As Integer
Dim clusters_() As Variant

numberOfClusters = Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").UsedRange.Columns(Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").UsedRange.Columns.Count).column - 1
numberOfDifferentPartsPlusCaption = Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row - 4

ReDim clusters_(numberOfClusters - 1, numberOfDifferentPartsPlusCaption)

For i = 0 To numberOfClusters - 1
   clusters_(i, 0) = Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").Cells(3, i + 2)

   For k = 1 To numberOfDifferentPartsPlusCaption
     clusters_(i, k) = Worksheets("Cluster Definition xy").Cells(k + 4, i + 2)
   Next   

Next

getClusters = clusters_
'WriteArrayToImmediateWindow (getClusters)

End Function
```

The function is called when initializing a userform and should work just fine, the result looks like this:

#### Array screenshot

[image: Array screenshot]

The error occurs in the line "clusters = getClusters()" and indicates a type mismatch.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim clusters() as Variant
Dim numberOfClusters, i As Integer
'ReDim clusters(UBound(getClusters(), 1) - LBound(getClusters(), 1), UBound(getClusters(), 2) - LBound(getClusters(), 2))

clusters = getClusters()

numberOfClusters = UBound(clusters, 1) - LBound(clusters, 1) + 1

For i = 0 To numberOfClusters
  something
Next

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm afraid I'm missing something extremely basic here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what is error description?

Comment: Mismatch of types